# Issue pushing working rails 4.0 app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am going through the one month rails where I have been updating things to get it to work with rails 4.  I have been successful except when I try to get the postgresql database working with the website.

I get the application error on the website and when I comb through the logs I get this not descriptive error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=omrails-scj.herokuapp.com request_id=cc4ff49d-c3dc-41ee-b999-730cc2a56628 fwd="98.193.89.149" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is the github address: https://github.com/CaptainChemist/omrails

Here is my gem file:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0.beta2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'



group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

One question I had about pushing to heroic was how to set up the production.rb file.  I added this code:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'omrails-scj.herokuapp.com:3000'}
```

Is that the right way to do it? I have run rake db:migrate and that runs with no issues.Also, is there a better place to go besides heroku logs -t to see what is going on?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I think these are the full logs Thanks for asking me to post those I didn't realize I was getting the error right in the beginning.

my application controller was:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
```

changing it to this fixed it:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController



2014-10-26T02:54:13.082222+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-10-26T02:54:13.082246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0.beta2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:49505
2014-10-26T02:54:13.082249+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-10-26T02:54:13.082250+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-10-26T02:54:13.082252+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083057+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Base (NameError)
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083059+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083061+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083067+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083069+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083070+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083074+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `e
ach'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083077+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083086+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083088+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083096+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083098+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083102+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083104+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083108+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/application.rb:349:in `initialize!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083110+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083113+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083114+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083121+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083127+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083131+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083132+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083135+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083138+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/server.rb:339:in `wrapped_app'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083145+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/server.rb:274:in `start'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083149+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083151+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083155+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2014-10-26T02:54:1
3.083160+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083162+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083165+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-10-26T02:54:13.083167+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-10-26T05:18:35.811914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=omrails-scj.herokuapp.com request_id=7f4e851d-6e1b-4d7d-bac2-dda8cc51f0af fwd="98.193.89.149" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Strongly recommend loggly for logging. We use that in our production environment and it works great. There's a free plan that you can install on your app.

Comment: Can you post full heroku logs because that single line is not much of a use. In default_url_options you don't need to specify port number. It should simply be `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'omrails-scj.herokuapp.com'}`

Comment: it's been a long time since I deployed to heroku, but as far as I can remember you'd also the gem taps to go along with 'pg'. Check this heroku blog for more details: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku.